# Will system create an api instance when calling a .NET RESTful api?

Tags: c#, asp.net, api

When calling a RESTful API, will the system **create** and **store** an instance of that API in memory? Will a global variable value that changed in one method be saved to memory? Can I get **access** to that global variable in another method in the same API?

For example, I have a RESTful API like this:

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    private ApplicationDbContext _context;
    private bool _isTest;

    public TestController()
    {
        _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
        _isTest = false;
    }

    // GET /api/test
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult GetTest()
    {
       _isTest = true;
       //some code...
       return Ok();
    }

    // DELETE /api/test/{id}
    [HttpDelete]
    public void RemoveTest(int id)
    {
       if (_isTest)
       {
           //other code...
           Console.WriteLine("Success!");
       }
    }
}
```

If I call the GET method first and then call the DELETE method, would console output "Success"?

Comment: Well, you could have quit easily tried the code to see what happens.

Comment: No. The controller is created and destroyed with each HTTP request. If you need to persist something between requests, you could use a session variable, an application variable, or a global/static variable.

Comment: you mean the `TestController`? as JohnWu stated, it will be remade for every HTTP Requests. you can use static variable and whether you can access it or not, depends on the access level (e.g. `public`, `protected`, `internal`, or `private`)